# populating select box from database and also adding reccuring rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

[image]

I have done till here like if I add row it is adding. As first row it is dynamically populating from service type generates service name as same it should happen for second third row but not happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.addRow').on('click',function(){
    addRow();
    var i=1;
  });

  function addRow(){
    i++; 
    var tr = '<tr id="row'+i+'">'+
                    '<td>'+                     
                    '<select class="form-control input-lg dynamic" name="service_type[]" id="service_type" data-parsley-required="true" data-dependent="service_name">'+
                                '<option value="">Select Service Type</option>'+
                                @foreach ($services as $service )
                                  '<option value="{{ $service->service_type }}">{{ $service->service_type }}</option>'+
                                @endforeach
                              '</select>'+                        

                            '</td>'+
                  '<td>'+
                      '<select class="form-control input-lg dynamic" name="service_name[]" id="service_name" data-parsley-required="true">'+
                        '<option value="">Select Service name</option>'+
                      '</select>'+
                    '</td>'+
                  '<td><select class="form-control" name="service_sess[]" id="service_sess" data-parsley-required="true">'+
                                '<option value="">Select Sessions</option>'+
                                '<?php 

                                    for($i=0; $i<=20; $i++)
                                    {

                                        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                                    }
                                   ?>'+
                              '</select></td>'+
                  '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</td>'+
                '</tr>';
              $('tbody').append(tr);

  };
  i=1;
  $('tbody').on('click','.remove',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.dynamic').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
          var select = $(this).attr("id");
          var value = $(this).val();
          var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
          var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
          $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('StandardPackageController.fetch') }}",method:"POST",data:{select:select,value:value,_token:_token,dependent:dependent},
            success:function(result)
            {
              $('#'+dependent).html(result);
            }
          })
        }


    });

  });


</script>
```

As I showed in the image the second row is not dynamically populating. As I am very new to this laravel I am unable to find mistakes.Please help me i am stuck in this.

Comment: move `var i=1;` outside and also check your dev tools console

Comment: where should i move var i=1; console is giving Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status) and Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: you can't really append PHP code with js as there isn't a PHP interpreter running on the web browser which can process it

Comment: @DinoNumić i not sure which php code you are telling

Comment: @chaitra you are using php loops for generating options when appending the row. The server needs to process it first and then give it to you. Nothing will happen if you add it yourself after the page is served.

Comment: @DinoNumić but that option is not a problem it is working the previous drop downs like service type fetches service name from data base is not working.